# How to find the occurrence count of sequence's largest element in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, max, var, find-occurrences

C++ beginner here. I'm trying to write a program **without the usage of arrays** that would take a N number and allow the user to write a sequence of elements consisting of the N number (e.g. the **N** is **5**, then the sequence of elements should be consisted of **5** integers (e.g. 8,21,7,21,10)). Then the program should count how much does the max element of the sequence occurr (in the example the output should be **2**, because the max number is **21**, which occurrs **2** times).
Here is the code I've wrote so far, which detects the max nubmer of the sequence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n , n_seq, count = 0;
  int max = INT_MIN;
  
  
  cin>>n;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin>>n_seq;

    if(n_seq > max)
    {
      
      max = n_seq;
      
    }    
  }  
  cout<<max;
}
```

But I can't figure out the rest on how to increment the **count** variable each time the max nubmer occurs.

Comment: `if (n_seq == max) count++`?

Comment: Additional to @AlanBirtles, the counter must be reset to 0, if a new max is found.

Comment: @SebastianH Or to one, depending on where the test is done.

Comment: @SebastianH I was trying not to completely write their homework for them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the count when `n_seq == max` and when you encounter a new maximum number you need to reset the counter:

```
if(n_seq > max)
{
  counter = 1;
  max = n_seq;
  
} else if (n_seq == max) {
   ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, n_seq, count = 0;
    int max = INT_MIN;


    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> n_seq;

        if (n_seq > max) {
            count = 1;
            max = n_seq;
        } else if(max == n_seq)
            ++count;

    }
    std::cout << max << std::endl;
    std::cout << count << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n , n_seq, count = 0;
  int max = INT_MIN;
  
  
  cin>>n;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin>>n_seq;

    if(n_seq > max)
    {          
      max = n_seq;
      count = 1;
    }    
    else if(n_seq == max){
      count++;
    }
  }  
  cout<<max;
}
```